# Remove horizontal scroll in block with "position:absolute" divs inside

Tags: css, css-position

http://codepen.io/evilandfox/pen/EVJeqm

I am making mobile site width sidebars, that are showing by swiping left and right.

There is a div container, that is including three other div blocks: menu (left sidebar), content and right sidebar. Sidebars positioned on the left and right side of content with "position:absolute". So adding classes on swiping is showing left or right sidebar by changing left position of container.

The problem is that container has horizontal scroll bar. "overflow: hidden" does not works. Do you Have any ideas?

So, HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-sidebar">
    I am menu
  </div>
  <div class="right-sidebar">
    I am additional content
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    I am content
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container > div {
  height: 200px;
}
.container-show-left-sidebar {
  left: 300px;
}
.container-show-right-sidebar {
  right: 300px;
}

.content {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.left-sidebar,
.right-sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.left-sidebar {
  background-color: tomato;
  left: -300px;
}
.right-sidebar {
  background-color: yellow;
  right: -300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add overflow: hidden to .container, but you're going to need to shift your left hand side sidebar to left: 0 and your right hand side sidebar to right: 0 when they're clicked.

Currently, if you open a sidebar the content area shifts only - you need to bring the sidebars in from outside of the container as well.

I've made a Codepen fork for you with a few changes:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPgyPg

Firstly, instead of shifting the content left or right we will apply padding to the left and right sides, as the sidebars are positioned to the edges of the container we would end up with 300px of white space on either side.

Secondly we'll use some event delegation instead of having JS in onclick attributes on your buttons and apply classes to your sidebars to move them in and out:

```
// When your show content button is clicked
$('#show-content').on('click', function() {

    // Remove both left and right classes to reset padding
    $('#container').removeClass('container-show-right-sidebar container-show-left-sidebar');

    // Remove active classes from both sidebars
    $('.right-sidebar, .left-sidebar').removeClass('active');
});

// When your left sidebar button is clicked
$('#show-left-sidebar').on('click', function() {

    // Remove the right sidebar class if it's applied and add the left sidebar classs
    $('#container')
        .addClass('container-show-left-sidebar')
        .removeClass('container-show-right-sidebar');

    // Remove active class from right sidebar
    $('.right-sidebar').removeClass('active');

    // Add active class to left sidebar
    $('.left-sidebar').addClass('active');
});

// When your rightsidebar button is clicked
$('#show-right-sidebar').on('click', function() {

    // Remove the leftsidebar class if it's applied and add the rightsidebar class
    $('#container')
        .removeClass('container-show-left-sidebar')
        .addClass('container-show-right-sidebar');

    // Add active class to right sidebar
    $('.right-sidebar').addClass('active');

    // Remove active class from left sidebar
    $('.left-sidebar').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: @Rinat no problems, I would't recommend just adding overflow: hidden to the entire body of your page - it may be a quick fix but it could cause issues down the track. You should always fix overflow issues on parent elements themselves first.

Answer (score 0):

I added `overflow:hidden` to `body` and it is working. Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWOeaE

Comment: Applying overflow:hidden to the entire body is a bandaid solution, it's important to be able to identify unintended body overflow and by hiding it for one specific problem you could potentially make identifying other problems more difficult down the track. https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/